# Find the values of $a,b,c$ such that a matrix has infinite, unique, and no solutions.

Tags: matrices

Find the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that a matrix has infinite, unique, and no solutions.

$$x+y=0$$
$$y+z=0$$
$$x+z=0$$
$$ax+by+cz=0$$

We can't use determinants so I turned the equations into an augmented matrix:

\begin{matrix}
         1&1&0&0 \\
         0&1&1&0 \\
         1&0&1&0 \\
         a&b&c&0 \\
        \end{matrix}

And then got this:

\begin{matrix}
         1&1&0&0 \\
         0&1&1&0 \\
         0&a-b&-c&0 \\
         0&0&2&0 \\
        \end{matrix}

So in order to have a system with infinite solutions I said that $a-b=0$ and $-c=0$ meaning that $a=b$ and $c=0$. And to have a system with unique solution; $a-b=1$ so $a=1+b$. So far I don't know if that's correct, I don't really know how to solve these kinds of analytical problems and I have no idea how to proceed to find the values of $a.b.c$ so I have no solutions.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is that second line supposed to be $y+x$ or should it be $y+z$?

Comment: First, terminology: matrices don't have solutions. A system of equations may, or may not have solutions. Second, what you have is a homogeneous system, so "no solution" is impossible --- can you see why it's guaranteed that there is at least one solution?

Comment: @Mike Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, again my bad. I can see now why. But the others are correct?

Comment: If you ignore the 4th equation, how many solutions does the system have? Then, can remembering the 4th equation (thus imposing an additional condition on solutions) increase the number of solutions?

Comment: If I ignore the 4th equation and $a-b=0$ and $-c=0$ then I'd have infinite solutions, but if I take into account 4th equation and $a-b=1$ then I'd have a unique solution.

Comment: Huh? The 4th equation is $ax+by+cz=0$. If you ignore that one, how many solutions does the remaining system of three equations have?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant the fourth line in the matrix. If I ignore that one, the system has a unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

If we solve
\begin{cases}
x+y=0\\
y+z=0\\
z+x=0,
\end{cases}
then we get $x=y=z=0$. $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ is also a solution of
\begin{cases}
x+y=0\\
y+z=0\\
z+x=0\\
ax+by+cz=0,
\end{cases}
but nonzero solution can't exist. Therefore, given system has unique solution for all $a,b,c$.

Meanwhile, we may simply say that given system of linear equations is equivalent to
\begin{cases}
x+y=0\\
y+z=0\\
z+x=0,
\end{cases}
because $ax+by+cz$ is linear combination of $x+y,y+z,z+x$. That can be justified since
$$
ax+by+cz=\frac{a+b-c}{2}(x+y)+\frac{-a+b+c}{2}(y+z)+\frac{a-b+c}{2}(z+x).
$$