# Finding values such that a linear system has some number of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that the system of linear equations has:
>
> 1. exact one solution
> 2. an infinite number of solution
> 3. no solution 
>      \begin{align}
>    x+5y+z&=0  \\
>    x+6y-z&=0  \\
>    2x+ay+bz&=c
>    \end{align}

I have done progress to solving the augmented matrics giving:
$$\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -11c/(2a+b-22) \\ 2c/(2a+b-22) \\ c/(2a+b-22) \end{bmatrix} .$$

From there am confused in finding the values $a$, $b$ and $c$.
Please help me to work this one out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the values of $a,b,c$ such that a matrix has infinite, unique, and no solutions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315462/find-the-values-of-a-b-c-such-that-a-matrix-has-infinite-unique-and-no-solut)

Comment: make a value equal to zero and solve for the corresponding value?

Comment: okay so from calculating, is a= 11, b= 0 and c=0 ?

Comment: does that make sense?

Comment: i believe a+2b=22 should be 2a + b = 22, from the equation above, therefore a = 11 making 2a + b = 22... correct me if am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the second we get
$$y-2z=0$$
Multiplying the first equation by $-2$ and adding to the third:
$$y(a-10)+z(b-2)=c$$ with $$y=2z$$ we obtain:
$$z(2a-22+b)=c$$
Can you finish?
From here we get
If $$2a+b-22\neq 0$$ then $$z=\frac{c}{2a+b-22}$$
If $$2a-22+b=0$$ then we get
$$0\cdot z=c$$
If $$c\ne 0$$ then no solutions.
If $$c=0$$ then $$z$$ is a real number.

Comment: The integer numbers are hard things, thank you very much!

Comment: The natural numbers are made by God, the others by men!

Comment: which equation did you multiply by -1 ?

Comment: The first equation, as written above!

Comment: from my calculation i got a= 11 , b =0 and c= 0, does it looks correct? and from there making z = 0

Answer (score 0):

If $2a+b-22\ne 0$ then the three equations have a single unique solution, as you have found.

If $2a+b-22=0$ then the left hand side of the third equation is a linear combination of the left hand sides of the first two equations. For example if $a=9$ and $b=4$ then we have

$2x + 9y + 4z = 3(x+5y+z) - (x+6y-z)$

If in addition $c=0$ then the third equation is consistent with the first two equations but gives us no further information. How many solutions are there in this case ?

On the other hand if $c \ne 0$ then the third equation is inconsistent with the first two equations. How many solutions are there in this case ?